# Trying to read a large csv with polars

Tags: python, etl, python-polars

I'm trying to read a large file (1,4GB pandas isn't workin) with the following code:

```
base = pl.read_csv(file, encoding='UTF-16BE', low_memory=False, use_pyarrow=True)
base.columns
```

But in the output is all messy with lots os \x00 between every lettter.
What can i do, this is killing me hahaha

I already tried a lot of encodings but none of them worked.

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your csv file before and after `polar` reading the csv file.  
one line from the csv and one line from the `polar.read_csv'  
In-between, depending on what's causing the character, two things might assist. 1. replace or 2. use `'utf-16-le'` encoding for the null byte (\x00).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried reading with open function?

```
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read().replace(b'\x00', b'')
base = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data), encoding='UTF-16BE', low_memory=False, use_pyarrow=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run `file -i file.csv` are getting UTF-16BE as the encoding? If it is, may be the file contains those "\X00" null characters and you have to remove it.

Comment: On macOS, just `file input.csv` (without`-i`).